# ssh to one machine and than another wihout password

Tags: ssh, password, key-authentication

If I ssh a server from my work PC, I do not have to enter password, it uses keys for passwordless authentication.

Yet If I use vpn and ssh to connect to my work PC (with a password) and then ssh to the said server then I am requested to enter password. Are there some parameters I am missing?

Home machine is Win10, all work machines run Linux

Comment: You are probably not loading your keyfile with `ssh-add` when you connect to your workstation via VPN.

Comment: so just run ssh-add when connected to work machine?

Comment: apparently I need start agent eval `ssh-agent -s` and ssh-add asks for a pathphrase

Comment: You can use `ssh -v` to debug what ssh thinks it is doing, in particular which key it is offering.